# Is "zweisprachige Ausgaben" the right expression?

Tags: translation, resource

I like to re-read in German translation my favorite authors<sup>1</sup>, and I enjoy it even more when they are in the form of dual-language editions.

To my surprise, however, I'm having a difficult time *searching* for dual-language editions aimed at the German-speaking market.<sup>2</sup>

More specifically, when I include "zweisprachige Ausgabe" or "zweisprachige Ausgaben" among the search terms, the hits that come up mention only books in the original language (i.e. rather than dual-language, these editions appear to be the original ones).  To see what I mean, [this](http://www.google.com/search?num=100&hl=en&rls=en&q=%22zweisprachige%20Ausgabe%22%20%7C%20%22zweisprachige%20Ausgaben%22%20%22alice%20munro%22&oq=%22zweisprachige%20Ausgabe%22%20%7C%20%22zweisprachige%20Ausgaben%22%20%22alice%20munro%22&gs_l) is what I get when I Google for:

```
"alice munro" "zweisprachige ausgabe" | "zweisprachige ausgaben"
```

Two possibilities come to mind: either

1. "zweisprachige Ausgabe" does not (or not *necessarily*) mean what I think it does; or
2. I happen to have an uncanny predilection for works that have not appeared as *zweisprachige Ausgaben*.

If the first possibility is the case, is there some *other* search term (besides *zweisprachige Ausgabe(n)*, that is) that would yield better results?

If the second one is the case, is there some way to search for *zweisprachige Ausgaben* that would maximize the number of such editions I actually find?  E.g., is there some publisher, or online bookseller, that has offers a substantial, and easily searchable, collection of such editions?

<sub><sup>1</sup>To be more precise, I should have written "those among my favorite works of fiction that were originally written in a language that I can read more comfortably than I can read German".  Hence, I'm not interested in "zweisprachige Ausgaben" of, e.g., Stanisław Lem's brilliant stories, since, unfortunately, I can't read a word of Polish.</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup>Why not read dual-language editions of works originally written in German?  Because I know that translation is a very difficult and very subtle art, and I feel in a far better position to judge it when the original language is one which I can already read fluently.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

It is probably one of the disadvantages of a search machine when it comes to finding exactly what you were searching.

My different approach with accessing a bookshop's webpage directly reveals a lot of interesting literature in bilingual editions:

- [Amazon.com "bilingual edition german"](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=bilingual+edition+german&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Abilingual+edition+german)
- [Amazon.de "Belletristik zweisprachig"](http://www.amazon.de/belletristik-zweisprachige-ausgaben-B%C3%BCcher/s?ie=UTF8&page=1&rh=n%3A186606%2Ck%3ABelletristik%20%2F%20Zweisprachige%20Ausgaben)
- [Bol.de](http://www.bol.de/shop/home/suche/any/?sswg=ANY&sq=zweisprachig&fftrkui=zweispr&timestamp=1362240021008)

I am sure there will be similar results when searching in a shop in your country. The links above should also give you the [ISBN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Book_Number) of a given book to start  a search.