# Bilingual (German/English) Novel Resources

Tags: learning, resource, book

I want to ask where I can find/buy in pdf format bilingual beginner-intermediate level german novels similar to penguin parallel text novels. I searched but could not find a good resource.

Comment: "Farmer Giles of Ham" (J.R.R. Tolkien) is a good bilingual text novel, but I can't find an ebook version.

Comment: dtv zweisprachig is a German series.

Comment: I had the Russian version of "First Reader Erste englische Lesestücke" so I assume the English version could help you to start. The level is really beginner.

Comment: related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6278/is-zweisprachige-ausgaben-the-right-expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About.com provides a list of dual-language books: [LINK](http://german.about.com/library/bldualbk.htm).

- Demian - A Dual Language Book
- Siddharta - A Dual Language Book
- Great German Poems of the Romantic Era/Berühmte Gedichte der Deutschen Romantik
- 103 Great Poems/103 Meistergedichte
- Best Short Stories/Die schönsten Erzählungen
- Death in Venice & A Man and His Dog/Der Tod in Venedig & Herr und Hund
- Five Great German Short Stories
- German Stories/Deutsche Erzählungen
- German Short Stories 2/Deutsche Kurzgeschichten 2

Additionally, you can find some children's books at a site like [this](http://www.languagelizard.com/German-s/2729.htm).

Also, I know of at least one site with free PDF children's books (only German, but pretty basic, [LINK](http://www.childrensbooksforever.com/childrenpages/German1.html)).

Answer (score 2):

I found a site for reading parellel texts:

http://paralleltext.io/

for example, Siddartha from Herman Hesse

http://paralleltext.io/read/?b=de-en-siddhartha

[image]

(click the Hamburger menu and then

[image]

I can't find a direct link or full catalog, but here are some suggestions from the site:

[image]

---

in this case, also available from Project Gutenberg:

https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/search/?query=Siddhartha&submit_search=Go%21